# Is there a short way to implement Default for a struct that has a field that does not implement Default?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that has 20 fields:

```rust
struct StructA {
    value1: i32,
    value2: i32,
    // ...
    value19: i32,
    day: chrono::NaiveDate,
}
```

I'd like to impl `Default` trait for `StructA`. I tried to add `#[derive(Default)]` to the struct, but `chrono::NaiveDate` doesn't implement `Default`.

I then tried to implement `Default` for `StructA`:

```rust
impl Default for StructA {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            value1: Default::default(),
            value2: Default::default(),
            // ...
            value19: Default::default(),
            day: chrono::NaiveDate::from_ymd(2021, 1, 1),
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but the parts of `value1` through `value19` are redundant. Is there a solution with less code?

- I defined `StructA` to deserialize JSON data via serde-json so I can't change the struct's definition.
- A value of `day: chrono::NaiveDate` is always given from JSON data, so I want to avoid `day: Option<chrono::NaiveDate>`.

Comment: I would prefer smaller structs to manage, inner pattern can be applied also : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a187cbf9d35a2b55aaf82ba32eb4dd2c

Comment: @ÖmerErden Yes. Your comment is a better way. But now, I defined the StructA for serialize/deserialize existing JSON data. So I can't change the structure of StructA.

Comment: You can always implement custom serializer/deserializer to represent your data in a different structure, actually If you are using serde   `#[serde(flatten)]` would easily solve your problem with the inner pattern.

Comment: I didn't know `#[serde(flatten)]`. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [derivative](https://docs.rs/crate/derivative/2.2.0) crate makes this kind of thing a breeze:

```
#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Default)]
struct StructA {
    value1: i32,
    value2: i32,
    // ...
    value19: i32,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "NaiveDate::from_ymd(2021, 1, 1)"))]
    day: NaiveDate,
}
```

If you want to avoid external crates, your options are:

- the approach you already used, with the downside that you must name all the fields. Also note that you don't need to repeat `Default::default()` for each numeric field, a simple `0` will work as well.
- make `day` an `Option` and derive `Default`, with the downside that it will default to `None`, bear a size penalty, and you'll have to `unwrap()` at run-time to access it.
- make `day` a newtype that wraps `NaiveDate` and implements `Default` to set it to the desired value, with the downside that you'll need to access the `NaiveDate` through a (zero-cost) field or method.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a custom function into value instead of just "NaiveDate::from_ymd(2021, 1, 1)"?

Comment: @qwer What do you mean by "pass a custom function"? You can certainly call any function you want, not just `NaiveDate::from_ymd()`.

Answer (score 3):

That's a rather dirty trick, but you can wrap your date in an `Option`, and it has an implementation of `Default`. Then you won't need to implement `Default` on your own, you can derive it. To keep the same semantics of `StructA::default()` you'll need to write your own method (luckily Rust allows to define `default()` method besides already derived `Default::default()`) [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=720a31eb575e16169f8010ffa8914e3b)

```
use chrono;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct StructA {
  value1: i32,
  value2: i32,
  value19: i32,
  day: Option<chrono::NaiveDate>,
}

impl StructA {
  fn default() -> Self {
    let mut instance: Self = Default::default();
    instance.day = Some(chrono::NaiveDate::from_ymd(2021, 1, 1));
    instance
  }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", StructA::default());
    // StructA { value1: 0, value2: 0, value19: 0, day: Some(2021-01-01) }
}
```

Downsides of this version:

- Need to `.unwrap()` the date everywhere it's used
- Two methods with same name `default`, but one is `Self::default` which fills the date as I implemented and the other is `Default::default` which fills the date with `None`, you'll need to be careful which you call (calling `StructA::default()` invokes `Self::default()`)

**EDIT.** Please be careful with this answer (details in the comments by @user4815162342)

In short - the last downside of having two different `.default()` methods in one type is dangerous in generic methods with `T: Default` arguments, because in this case will be called `Default::default()`, which initializes the `day` field to `None`. The worst part of this effect, is that compiler won't ever warn you about it, thus forcing you to spend your time debugging in case of a bug.

There's one similar approach suggested by @ÖmerErden, where you can again wrap the date into another type, to which you implement `Default` on your own. This will ensure that your field will always be initialized, but still forces you to somehow *"unwrap"* the value. In case of wrapping `NaiveDate` into a tuple struct, you can unwrap as simply as `instance.day.0` or implement `Deref` to this wrapper and unwrap with `*instance.day`

```
use chrono;
use std::ops::Deref;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct NaiveDateWrapper(chrono::NaiveDate);

impl Default for NaiveDateWrapper {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self(chrono::NaiveDate::from_ymd(2021, 1, 1))
    }
}

impl Deref for NaiveDateWrapper {
    type Target = chrono::NaiveDate;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct StructA {
  value1: i32,
  value2: i32,
  value19: i32,
  day: NaiveDateWrapper,
}

fn main() {
    let v = StructA::default();
    println!("{:?}", v.day.0);  
    println!("{:?}", *v.day);
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, also Wrapper struct  can be used to get rid of `unwrap` : `NaiveDateWrapper(chrono::NaiveDate)`

Comment: This trick will fail badly (and silently) when `StructA` is used in generic code where `T: Default` is required. It will silently invoke `Default::default()` and fail to initialize the struct correctly.

Comment: @user4815162342 can't agree more, but can be partially solved with what @Ömer Erden suggests - wrap the date type in some tuple struct and implement `Default` for it

Comment: That idea is probably the most elegant approach using just the standard library. I encourage you to edit your answer to feature it more prominently. I didn't downvote because I have a "competing" answer, but the dirty-trick solution from the answer is really dangerous in the face of generic code, and generic code is probably the reason the OP wants to implement `Default` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There is another crate called Educe https://docs.rs/educe/latest/educe/#default

Some code snippets.

```rs
#[macro_use] extern crate educe;

#[derive(Educe)]
#[educe(Default)]
struct Struct {
    #[educe(Default = 1)]
    f1: u8,
    #[educe(Default = 11111111111111111111111111111)]
    f2: i128,
    #[educe(Default = 1.1)]
    f3: f64,
    #[educe(Default = true)]
    f4: bool,
    #[educe(Default = "Hi")]
    f5: &'static str,
    #[educe(Default = "Hello")]
    f6: String,
    #[educe(Default = 'M')]
    f7: char,
}

#[derive(Educe)]
#[educe(Default)]
enum Enum {
    Unit,
    #[educe(Default)]
    Tuple(
        #[educe(Default(expression = "0 + 1"))]
        u8,
        #[educe(Default(expression = "-11111111111111111111111111111 * -1"))]
        i128,
        #[educe(Default(expression = "1.0 + 0.1"))]
        f64,
        #[educe(Default(expression = "!false"))]
        bool,
        #[educe(Default(expression = "\"Hi\""))]
        &'static str,
        #[educe(Default(expression = "String::from(\"Hello\")"))]
        String,
        #[educe(Default(expression = "'M'"))]
        char,
    ),
}

#[derive(Educe)]
#[educe(Default)]
union Union {
    f1: u8,
    f2: i128,
    f3: f64,
    f4: bool,
    #[educe(Default = "Hi")]
    f5: &'static str,
    f6: char,
}
```