# Writting a custom function for default value of a single member of struct in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

Based on these two questions ([Is there a short way to implement Default for a struct that has a field that does not implement Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68346169/is-there-a-short-way-to-implement-default-for-a-struct-that-has-a-field-that-doe) and [Only setting one field in a Rust `Default` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712973/only-setting-one-field-in-a-rust-default-implementation)), it looks like you can used the "derivative" package to do this. However, I am not sure what the right inputs/outputs are for the custom function

```
#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Default)]
struct StructA {
    x: u64,
    #[derivative(Default(value = "some_custom_func"))]
    y: u64,
}

pub fn some_custom_func() -> u64 {}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/latest/Default.html), `value = "..."` should contain an expression, not just the name of a function:

> You can use *derivative* to change the default value of a field in a `Default` implementation:
>
> ```
> #[derive(Debug, Derivative)]
> #[derivative(Default)]
> struct Foo {
>     foo: u8,
>     #[derivative(Default(value="42"))]
>     bar: u8,
> }
> ```

You could of course use a function call as the expression (`value = "some_custom_func()"`).

Comment: Right but what’s the right format for the input and output of that function? Does it have to return any special type?

Comment: @qwer I'm not sure I understand the question - the function itself is unimportant here, what matters is the _expression_ in `value="..."` must evaluate to the same type as the member (in this example, `u8`). So, for instance, you could have a function `foo` that returns `u8` directly and use it like `value="foo()"`. You could also do something fancier with another (possibly already existing function) like `fn bar(a: bool, b: bool) -> (u8, &str)` and use it like `value="bar(...).0"`.